# Update to Calendar Once Approved

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-calendar, approval

I have an Approval - Sharepoint 2010 workflow set up.

Staff fill in the form and submit and I then approve or reject. Once it has been approved I would like it to be entered into the calendar on SharePoint.

One major note, I don't have access to SharePoint Designer, it is not an option in my workplace.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need the access of SharePoint Designer. You have to add another action after approval. Add **Create List Item** action when it is approved.

**[Create List Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164026.aspx):**

> Creates a new list item in the list that you specify. You can supply
>   the fields and values in the new item. You can use this action
>   whenever you want a new item to be created with specific information.

Event Receiver is another option for you to check when item is being approved. But it requires much more work than if you use SPD.

Comment: That's unfortunate, as I said, I am not able to use Share Point designer. Thank you though

Comment: You can check when item is being approved by event receiver but it is costlier than SPD. Very easy to solve this using SPD

Comment: I can imagine so but we are not allowed SPD

Comment: Ok. Then use event receiver.

Comment: Can I do this with SP alone or do I need anything else?